# how i can find out last 4 weeks number of records?

Tags: mysql

my table structure was like

```
CREATE TABLE `survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `submitdate` datetime default NULL,
 `answer` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=499 ;
```

now i want to count number of records of last 4 weeks.

one thing is if suppose there is no records on particular week it should list as 0

here the example output is like

```
count(*) week 
  0      mon-sun  //29 oct -  4 nov every week starts from monday and ends with sunday 
  4      mon-sun  //5 nov -  11 nov
  45     mon-sun  //12 nov -  18 nov  last week 
  0      mon-sun  //18 nov - 25 nov  latest week
```

suppose today is monday then week range changes to latest week mon-sun.

Answer (score 1):

The query will looks like :

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    DATE(DATE_SUB(s.submitdate,INTERVAL(DAYOFWEEK(s.submitdate) - 2) DAY)) AS weekStart,
    ADDTIME(SUBTIME(SUBDATE(s.submitdate,INTERVAL(DAYOFWEEK(s.submitdate) - 8)DAY),TIME(s.submitdate)),MAKETIME(23,59,59)) AS weekEnd,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM survey s
GROUP BY weekStart
LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what is meant by 'wp.start' here. i am getting error Unknown column 'wp.start' in 'field list'

Comment: Sorry, I was already using this query, missed one replacement. This is not impossible that the weekStart is sunday... maybe will need just to add or remove one day (change -1 and -7).

Comment: week starts from monday not sunday

Comment: Edited, will return from monday 00h00 to sunday 23h59

Comment: ok i got your idea. s.submitdate) - 2 should vary from -1 to -7. so  i will try to put this in loop depending upon todays date. and thanks for your reply and answer.

Comment: Well not exactly. Dates will always be monday to sunday with values -2 and -8. The weekStart and weekEnd are calculated to be the monday and sunday closest from the s.submitdate.